# Creating a Android Video streaming app with a split Screen

Tags: android, video-streaming, split-screen

I am a performance test engineer looking to learn Android development to create a split screen video streaming app. I know there are multiple website which have a lot of tutorials for me to get the hang of android development but I would really appreciate if anyone can point me in the right direction so that I can take the correct steps to create this app.

I am really struggling to start it off and looking for people who can give me some initial pointers.

I know there are a lot of split screen video apps which shows two or more videos in parallel but I am working toward building my own app. Requesting to please help me start in the right direction.

Best Regards,

Pankaj S Harde

Answer (score 0):

you can use viewPager for this [Link is here for help](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager)

you can use it in different ways as you want or user requirement,
viewpager have different libraries you can also use these